# How do i read a special type of mail in a network share

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

The mail item selected from a folder of a network share has a strange looking icon, different from the regular type (attached image). It may have something to do with reporting read/unread status of a received mail. Maybe a different class altogether.

How do I read this type of mail in VBA?

[image]

```
Dim oSel As Outlook.Selection

Set oSel = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

Dim oEmail As Outlook.mailitem

Set oEmail = oSel.Item(1)    ' getting a 13 compile error in this line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `ReportItem` object, not `MailItem`. Declare oEmail as a generic object, and either use the `TypeName()` function to figure out the actual object type or read the `Class` property (all Outlook objects expose it) - for `MailItem` objects it will be 43 (`olMail`).